# How can I make my request asynchronously without importing a new file

Tags: excel, vba, web-services, asynchronous, soap

I am trying to perform a SOAP call but sometimes the response is thousands of record. I don't want Excel frozen while it is processing the responses but every example I've seen require importing a separate file with the async callback. Is there a way I can do this without the extra file?

```
Public Function SendPost(currentTableAltIden As String, altIdentifiers() As String, Optional aSync As Boolean = True)
Dim t As XMLHTTP60
Dim r As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim nodeList As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim i As Integer
Dim listLengthControl As Integer
Dim listCounter As Integer
Dim xmlHelper As AsyncHelper

  i = 0
   Set t = Transport
   Set xmlHelper = New AsyncHelper
       xmlHelper.init t
   t.Open "POST", EndPointUrl, aSync
   
   
   t.send Text
   
   Set r = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
   r.aSync = False
   r.validateOnParse = False
   r.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", " xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'"
   r.LoadXML t.responseText
   
   Set nodeList = r.SelectNodes("//result//" & currentTableAltIden)
   listLengthControl = nodeList.Length
   
   While listCounter <> listLengthControl
      For i = LBound(altIdentifiers) To UBound(altIdentifiers)
                  Debug.Print r.SelectNodes("//result//" & currentTableAltIden & "//" & altIdentifiers(i))(listCounter).Text
                  WorkWebServiceTemp.Cells(TableDataRowNum + listCounter, i + 1).value = r.SelectNodes("//result//" & currentTableAltIden & "//" & altIdentifiers(i))(listCounter).Text
      Next i
      listCounter = listCounter + 1
   Wend

      
End Function
```

Comment: No, you can't do this without the extra file - not in VBA. Use Office-JS (or .NET interop / VSTO) if you want asynchronous! VBA code only gets one single thread. If that thread is busy processing a request, it's not available for Excel to be responsive (or for other VBA code to run)

Comment: "every example I've seen" -such as what?  Please provide an example of the approach you don't want to use.

Comment: @TimWilliams TIL, thanks. Still, one single thread is available; the async callbacks will run sequentially.

Comment: Why don't you want to import the extra file?  It's really not a big deal...

Comment: examples such as this http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php?title=Asynchronous_HTTP_Request_Class&diff=8862&oldid=8861#The_AsyncHTTP_Class

Comment: i don't want to import a file because this is a modification to something existing and if there is a solution that doesn't require an extra file it would make the modification easier

Comment: So, you want to stick to a purely procedural paradigm *and* make it async? That's self-contradictory. Procedural code runs top-to-bottom, and if a non-blocking operation is invoked, problems happen (e.g. object accessed before its reference is assigned, etc.). If you want to handle the request asynchronously, you MUST switch to an event-driven, more object-oriented paradigm. There's absolutely no way your current code could possibly be tweaked in any manner that will make it execute differently.

Comment: "importing a file" -> adds a class module to your project, leaves existing code alone, ergo, much less risky than tweaking (and breaking) existing code.

Comment: Work-around below but really just a challenge for me rather than an approach you're likley to use.  Still involves adding code to your project - as @MathieuGuindon points out though, there is a fundamental difference between synch and asynch fetch - it will never just be a matter of adding a line of code to make the switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun...

```
Sub AsyncTester()

    Static col As Collection

    Set col = New Collection
    col.Add AsyncFetcher("https://stackoverflow.com/", New clsTest)
    col.Add AsyncFetcher("https://google.com/", New clsTest)
    col.Add AsyncFetcher("https://news.ycombinator.com/", New clsTest)

    Debug.Print "finished setup"

End Sub


Function AsyncFetcher(url As String, callBackObject As Object)
    Dim sc As Object
    Set sc = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
    sc.Language = "JScript"
    sc.AddCode "var objXML, theUrl, objCallBack;"
    sc.AddCode " function callBack(){objCallBack.Report(objXML.readystate + ' ' + theUrl);}  " & vbLf
    sc.AddCode " function fetch(url, obj){                                    " & vbLf & _
               "   objCallBack = obj; theUrl = url;                           " & vbLf & _
               "   objXML = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHttp.6.0');          " & vbLf & _
               "   objXML.onreadystatechange = callBack;                      " & _
               "   objXML.open(""GET"", url, true);                           " & vbLf & _
               "   objXML.send();                                             " & vbLf & _
               "}                                                             "

    sc.Run "fetch", url, callBackObject

    Set AsyncFetcher = sc

End Function
```

clsTest:

```
Public Sub Report(s)
    Debug.Print s
End Sub
```

Comment: ^^^^ This. Note the paradigm shift: you're no longer *commanding* what's going to happen, you're *responding* to things happening. Why late-bind the `ScriptControl` though?

Comment: No reason - not a fully-thought-out thing but "just working"...